# Machine Learning Lottery

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python

I have lottery data and I want to use Scikit-Learn to create several different models starting with Regression(One vs All). I know the lottery is random, and impossible to predict, but I want to use machine learning to discover anything interesting about the data. When it comes to Regression, you need independent and dependent variables, an input and the target. Below is the head to my database. I want the date to be for forecasting, and balls 1-3 as independent variables, with the result column which is a string of the previous columns as the target/dependent variable. My question is: **could balls 1-3, which are all separate columns, combine to be the target (Results column)?**

```
Data Head:

            b1  b2  b3 Results
Date                          
1984-09-01   9   4   8     948
1984-09-03   1   5   3     153
1984-09-04   8   6   6     866
1984-09-05   5   6   9     569
1984-09-06   2   1   9     219
```

Comment: Welcome to our site, Jordan.  Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts and then take a few minutes to review our [help] so you can use the site more effectively.

Comment: One interesting question you could try to answer with your dataset is whether the lottery is really random. https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-7152(93)90141-5 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2008.07.017 provide statistical tests. Be sure to run some power analysis, too, though.

Comment: For more interesting questions you would need more data, like the payout if the lottery game is parimutuel. Here is a video on a project on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNZRSYWOJBE

Answer (score 4):

You're asking for a linear model.

$$
\text{Results} = 100 \cdot \text{b1} + 10 \cdot \text{b2} + \text{b3} + 0\cdot \text{Date}
$$

This solution is trivial because $\text{Result}$ is exactly represented by its digits, and has no relation at all to $\text{Date}$.